# Can someone "wield" someone elses life

Tags: meaning

Can I use wield to something thats not physical like "the man is wielding a gun".
How often is it used.

Comment: Certainly non-physical things can be wielded. To "wield power" is a common expression. But what would it mean to wield a life?

Comment: Just about any word can be used metaphorically; but what is it you *mean* by "wielding" someone's life?

Comment: Like when someone is black mailing you and tell you what to do and stuff, controll over you

Comment: You wield a weapon, not the person who's being threatened by the weapon.

Answer (score 0):

No.  But you can *"hold someone's life in your hands"*.

You can also *"have the power of life and death over someone"*, *"make life miserable"* for someone, or *"beat someone to within an inch of their life"*.

Alternately, if you are wealthy and generous, you can *"set someone up for life"*, or *"give someone a new lease on life"* if you provide them an opportunity to *"turn their life around"*.  You can also *"breathe new life into someone (or something)"*.

A doctor might *"bring someone back to life"* if they are *"at death's door"*.

Lastly, if you seriously scare someone, you might say you *"scared the life out of them"* or *"scared them half to death"*.

There are, naturally, many [other idioms about life](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/life).